# Python - Using for loop with custom variable naming

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to do a (a think) rather simple task with **Python** but cannot seem to do it or find a way to do it. I'm trying to have a for loop where my variables are set to another variable with a custom number. It's a bit hard to explain, but my code will explain it better :

```
aha_aha1 = "1"
aha_aha2 = "wouh"
aha_aha3 = "yes !"
test = "my man !"

for i in range (0, 4):
  if aha_aha{i} = "yes !":
     test[i] == aha_aha{i}.format(i)
```

I want `test[i]` to be `aha_aha[i]` only when certain conditions are met, but my code above obviously doesn't work. Any help ?

Comment: you can't name variables `aha_aha1, aha_aha2, ..` and then select them according to the number in the name (i.e., `aha_aha{i}` does not exist in python). You must do a `list` and access them by index

Comment: Oh that's a shame. Thank you, will do this !

Comment: Use a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

If you really want those 'aha_x's:

```
d = {"aha_aha1" : "1", "aha_aha2" : "wouh", "aha_aha3" : "yes !"}
test = "my man !"

for i in range (0, 4):
  temp = "aha_aha"+str(i)
  if d.get(temp) == "yes !":
    #Do something
```

Comment: I'm getting my variables from an external source, and there are all like this something_1, something_2, etc...

Comment: @CommYov if you know that the variables are going to arrive in some known fixed format, this should help

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't understand what you are doing, but start from here at least:

```
aha_aha_list = ["1", "wouh", "yes !"]
test = "my man !"

for aha_aha in aha_aha_list:
    if aha_aha is "yes !":
        test = aha_aha

print(test)
```

Output:

```
yes !
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
do you want that?in python str type is unable to change,so you should chage str to list,and then chat list to str.
d = {'aha_aha1': '1', 'aha_aha2': 'wouh', 'aha_aha3': 'yes !'}
test = "my man !"
for i in range(0, 4):
    if d.get("aha_aha{i}".format(i=i),None) == "yes !":
        test = list(test)
        test[i] = d.get("aha_aha{i}".format(i=i))
        test = ''.join(test)
        
        
   print(test) #my yes !an !
```